# How to remove the the word "category" from the URL of a WordPress category NOT the post?

Tags: wordpress

I have a category by the name "mycategory".
The URL of the category is currently - http://mixerp.org/blog/blog/category/mycategory/

but I need to change that URL to - http://mixerp.org/blog/blog/mycategory/

I tried playing around with the permalink settings but unfortunately I was unable to solve my problem. Currently, I have set the permalink settings to "Day and name". Can anyone kindly help me on this ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Custom Permalink if the other options aren't working.
Make sure you delete the %category% part of the permalink, and this should solve your issue.

Comment: Well the thing is, right now under permalink settings I have selected "Day and Month" which gives me the following structure :

*http://mixerp.org/blog/blog//%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/

and there is no %category%, plus I dont wish to change that because then the link to my previous posts wont work. I somehow need to retain the links of my current posts and at the same time change the URL of my category.

Comment: Can you put that string into Custom
%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname% 
and see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by change in  .htaccess file,
First backup your .htaccess file. Then, open it and append the following line:

```
RewriteRule ^category/(.+)$ http://mixerp.org/blog/blog/$1 [R=301,L]

Once saved, your categories pages will be displayed like this:

http://mixerp.org/blog/blog/mycategory/
```

But i will prefer the answer given by Ronan Murphy, which is easy and safe

Comment: Thanks for the help but I do not have access to the server files. Moreover, I would not like to find myself bringing my blog down by messing around with backend files. I just want it to be fixed from the wordpress dashboard itself.