# I want to remove default “/category/” appering in category listing URL in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, permalinks

I need help on displaying URL for my Wordpress Blog

My permalink setting is 
domainname/%category%/category-name/

I want to show my category listing URL as 
domainname/category-health/

However, I can see the URL as
domainname/category/category-health/

Could anyone tell me how can I remove the "/category/" in the URL?

I have gone through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21722915/how-to-remove-the-the-word-category-from-the-url-of-a-wordpress-category-not-t) but I am not successful.

Comment: So you want 'domainname/category/health/'  where category is a fixed word `'category'` and not a placeholder? Please post a **valid** example of your expected output.

Comment: Hi...I found a solution to it. We have to change the settings -> permalinks -> category base to period or dot and then it works.. thanks a lot. I can mark this question as resolved.

Comment: I am using a category base as "." which fixes this issue.